# How do you delete rows with a certain object in pandas, python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column in my data that contains these kind of values

2

2

yes

2

yes

In python pandas how would I identify the entire row containing a string of letters and then delete or drop the entire row?

Thanks

Comment: df.drop(df[df['col'] == 2].index)

Comment: That seems to only return completed rows?

Comment: I populated all the rows that had missing values and it worked!!! THANKS!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully.  To check if a value is numeric in a column, use df['col'].str.isnumeric()  and for those that are false, drop.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df = df[~pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').isna()]
```

or

```
df = df[pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Comment: I tried both and it came up with this error

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

Comment: @KRidg, did you name your DataFrame as `pd`? `pd` is supposed to be an alias for pandas module...

Comment: No I don't think so, my DataFrame has a completely different name which I put in place of df. I left pd in the same position.

Comment: @KRidg, what is the output of `print(type(pd))`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to solve this.  I've included code to build the DataFrame,
find the string values and then drop them.  df.drop returns a modified copy
of the original df unless you specify inplace=True, so if you want, you can assign the original name of the df `df = df.drop...`, or use the inplace argument.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# build the df
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name' : [2, 2, 'yes', 2, 'yes']})
print(df)

  col_name
0        2
1        2
2      yes
3        2
4      yes

# ask what are the types in column
df.col_name.apply(type)

0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'int'>
4    <class 'str'>
Name: col_name, dtype: object

# you can see that the strings are in row 2 and 4
# and drop them like this
df.drop([2, 4], axis='rows')

  col_name
0        2
1        2
3        2
```